# Airflow DAG not getting triggered as expected

Tags: airflow

I have to set up an airflow DAG to run on every 2nd Monday of the month at 5am starting January2024. What should be the correct start date?

```
schedule_interval="0 5 * * mon#2"
```

I tried running for Dec2023 with start_date as datetime(2023, 12, 01). It was not triggered.